# how to do order by on a to_char column

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I have a following oracle query:

```
   SELECT a.USER_ID,
           c.first_name,
           c.last_name,
           TO_CHAR( b.logon_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS am') logon_date,
           NVL(TO_CHAR( b.logoff_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS am'), '') logoff_date,
           a.session_id
      FROM table a,
           table b,
           table c
       WHERE a.row_id >= start_row
               AND a.row_id <= end_row
               AND a.session_id = b.session_id
               AND a.USER_ID = b.USER_ID
               AND a.USER_ID = RTRIM(LTRIM(c.USER_ID))
      ORDER BY logoff_date DESC
```

query works fine if I remove the `order by`

I want to `order` the results of this query in `DESC` order based on `logoff_date` on which I am using `to_char` to make it a date with time in am/pm

I tried giving following as `order_by`

```
NVL(TO_CHAR( b.logoff_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS am'), '')
```

but results come back as:

```
03/03/2010 12:59:37 am
03/03/2010 12:53:12 pm
03/03/2010 12:41:40 pm
03/03/2010 12:19:38 am
03/03/2010 11:34:04 am
03/03/2010 10:41:47 am
03/03/2010 10:16:16 pm
03/03/2010 10:14:45 pm
03/03/2010 09:59:54 am
03/03/2010 07:36:17 pm
```

Comment: What happens if you run the SQL as shown.  You state that the query works fine if you remove the order by, which means it doesn't work fine when you have it.

Comment: it runs fine = if i dont want sorting
it doesn't run fine = if i want sorting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently you are ordering by the character value of your date because logoff_date references the alias `logoff_date` in the select (`NVL(TO_CHAR( ...))`). This character value will usually be ordered alphabetically and will not match the ordering of the DATE column.

If you want to order by the DATE value of the column, you will have to reference it precisely:

```
ORDER BY b.logoff_date
         ^^
```